# How can I enable the file upload permission?

Tags: actionscript-3, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to upload images generated in my Flash application to an album on Facebook.  This was working earlier in the year, but revisiting the code I now get the following OAuthException:

> (#324) Requires upload file

I am using the most recent version of the ActionSccript Facebook API.  The setup works like this:

First I do the authentication check with PHP to ensure users have granted permission before having to wait for the Flash to load.  I'm requesting the publish_stream and user_photos permissions. The access token comes back correctly.

Once the user is authenticated the Flash is loaded and performs its own initialisation, passing `fileUpload=true` as part of the init object:

```
var initObject:Object = {
    channelUrl : "myChannelURL.html",
    fileUpload : true
}
Facebook.init(
    'myAppID',
    myCallbackFunction,
    initObject,
    myAccessToken
);
```

This seems to work as expected, the callback receives the uid of the current user.

At the end of my application I POST a Bitmap object to a predetermined album:

```
Facebook.api(
    albumID+"/photos",
    onImagePost,
    {
        message:"",
        image:new Bitmap(myBitmapData),
        fileName:''
    },
    URLRequestMethod.POST
);
```

At this point Facebook returns a 400 response:

```
"error": {
    "message": "(#324) Requires upload file",
    "type": "OAuthException"
}
```

What more do I need to do to ensure that this permission is being included?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that this was not a permissions error at all.  Since I last deployed this code Facebook have tightened up their restrictions a bit, and the `fileName` parameter passed as part of the api call can no longer be an empty string. Simply passing any old text as a file name fixes the problem.

```
Facebook.api(
    albumID+"/photos",
    onImagePost,
    {
        message:"",
        image:new Bitmap(myBitmapData),
        fileName:'FILE'  // required to be non-empty
    },
    URLRequestMethod.POST
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if this is a solution that can be translated into the Actionscript SDK... But, with the PHP SDK there is a method inside the facebook SDK that is called `setFileUploadSupport` - try looking in the code for a place to set that parameter to `true`.

Comment: I had looked into this, but the AS3 API is actually just a layer on top of the JavaScript API, which doesn't have a similar parameter as far as I can see. The only way I can see to pass it is as a parameter in the initialisation object, which I already do.